# How to print multiple instances of a variable in Swift

Tags: swift, swift-playground

In Swift, how can you print out a variable multiple times.
Say I had

```
var symbol = "*"
```

Can I do something like in JavaScript where you go

```
console.log(symbol * 4)
```

When I try to do this in Swift, an error comes back. Any way around this?

Comment: BTW, `console.log(symbol * 4)` in JavaScript outputs `NaN`, doesn't it?

Comment: @rintaro Maybe OP is thinking of Python - that's the only programming language I know of that lets you multiply strings :D

Answer (score 2):

You can very easily create an operator overload which will make this work.

```
func * (left: String, right: Int) -> String {
    var multipliedString = left
    for x in 1..<right {
        multipliedString += left
    }
    return multipliedString
}
```

Put that above your class, and then you can do something like:

```
println("Hello World" * 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no builtin operator for that in Swift.

You can use `Repeat` and `join` instead.

```
var symbol = "*"
println(join("", Repeat(count: 4, repeatedValue: symbol)))
```

`Repeat(count: 4, repeatedValue: symbol)` *virtually* creates `[symbol, symbol, symbol, symbol]`, then `join("", ...)` joins them using separator `""`.

Answer (score 2):

Combining solutions proposed by [rintaro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3804019/rintaro) and [Jeremy Pope](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4504601/jeremy-pope), you can do exactly what you want:

```
func * (left: String, right: Int) -> String {
    return join("", Repeat(count: right, repeatedValue: left))
}

var symbol: String = "*"
println(symbol * 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this - println(String(count: 4, repeatedValue: Character("*")))

Answer (score 0):

var symbol = "*"

print(String(repeating: symbol, count: 4))

// "****"